# Running matlab compiled exe into ubuntu machine - could not find version 8.1 of the MCR

Tags: python, matlab, ubuntu, wine

I have a mex function which I have converted into exe using windows. I am trying to run that exe into a ubuntu machine with command :

```
os.system('test.exe')
```

But, this exe doesnt works and it gives me error :

```
could not find version 8.1 of the MCR
Attempting to load mclmcrrt8_1.dll
Please install the correct version of MCR
```

I have kept mclmcrrt8_1.dll into the directory from where I am calling the exe using python. But, error is still there.

How I will run matlab compiled exe from ubuntu machine which do not have matlab?

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong - but you won't be able to run a windows `exe` on ubuntu.

Comment: then what is the way that I can run matlab function standalone?

Comment: In order to run things on ubuntu, you'll have to compile the executable on ubuntu as well - or at least on "some" linux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download and install MCR for Ubuntu. It is [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/index.html)

Comment: But, executable means It should run without that environment right?

Comment: I am afraid that you should run your program in this environment. Matlab does not give us much freedom to execute program.

Comment: MCR is freeware? or I need licence for it?

Comment: You should check this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/pricing_licensing.html?s_iid=plp_pl_CO_tb) in order to know the price. I am sorry. I have not used this before so cannot answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

First You should install MCR for your matlab version. If you are using Matlab R2013b means you have to download and install MCR for R2013b. It is in http://www.mathworks.in/products/compiler/mcr/index.html. For ubuntu you have only 64bit MCR because after R2012a mathworks stopped their mCR for 32 bit versions.

You said you have to execute your matlab code in ubuntu. So dont deploy your matlab code into exe. Deploy your code into java.